# How to get create time of uploaded file in java?

Tags: file-upload

I am uploading files by servlet/JSP. Now I am facing an issue about getting the created time of the uploaded file.

The problem is, when a file is uploaded to server, I get the created time and find it same as uploaded time. The file is created on server when uploading finishes...

Is it possible to get the original created time of an uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can  ty this workaround. When you upload the file, get the creation time and update a README.txt file on the server. This README.txt will have entries like this:
UploadedFileName: Creation Time of Upload File

Comment: the question is, how to get the creation time before uploading?